# In cypress is there any way to exclude element which has property display : none?

Tags: css-selectors, cypress, display

[image: 1]

I want to select only the div which don't have `style="display : none"`

```js
cy.get('div[class="table-wrap"]').filter(':visible')
  .contains('element_to_selected_inside_This_div')

cy.get('div[class="table-wrap"]').not('style="display: none;"')
  .contains('element_to_selected_inside_This_div')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is square brackets around the style attribute, same as you did for class attribute

```js
cy.get('div[class="table-wrap"]')
  .not('[style="display: none;"]')
  .contains('element_to_selected_inside_This_div')
  .should('have.length', 1)                         // only one is selected
```